# Check if rows and columns of matrices have more than one non-zero element?

Tags: matrix, procedural-programming

I am given a list of square matrices (with non numeric entries but abstract symbols which are assumed to take real values) and I want to write a function that returns True if the following condition is satisfied:

- All rows and columns of each matrix have **at most one** nonzero element.

In other words, a row or column can either have all elements zero, or all but one. Otherwise, the function should return False.

I could of course write a triple loop that goes through each matrix in the list, then each row and column, and counts non-zero elements, but I am wondering what would be the most clever and efficient way to do it.

Note that even if only one matrix in that list has a row or column with more than one non-zero elements, then there would be no need to check for the rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[mat_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ]&)] :=
 FreeQ[
  Through[{Total, Map[Total]} @ Unitize[mat]], 
  _?(# > 1 &)
 ]
```

The code uses `Unitize` to turn any non-zero number into 1. `Total` sums the columns of the unitized matrix; `Map[Total]` sums the rows. The sums are therefore counts of non-zero elements in each column vs. row. FreeQ checks whether any of those counts is higher than 1, which indicates that there was more than one non-zero element in that column vs. row.

Let's make some matrices to test:

```
SeedRandom[4563]
MatrixForm /@ 
 (list = 
   RandomChoice[{200, 10, 10, 10} -> {0, 1, 2, 3}, {10, 5, 5}])
```

[image: random matrices generated for test]

and apply our test function `f` to each:

```
f /@ list

(* Out: {False, True, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, True} *)
```

---

Following the comment and edit mentioning the presence of symbols rather than numbers, here is an alternative function:

```
ClearAll[fSym]
fSym[mat_] :=
 FreeQ[
   Through[{Total, Map[Total]}@mat],
   _Plus,
   -1
 ]
```

Same test, but with symbolic variables:

```
SeedRandom[4563]
MatrixForm /@ (listSym = 
   RandomChoice[{200, 10, 10, 10} -> {0, a, b, c}, {10, 5, 5}])
```

[image: list of matrices with symbols instead of numbers]

```
fSym /@ listSym

(* Out: {False, True, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, True} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, there is the following issue. My matrices do not have numeric elements but abstract symbols (that take real values). E.g. I would have something like {{a,0,0},{b,c,0},{0,0,0}}. In this case, your code does not work

Comment: @AG1123 I added an edit to the answer to take that into account.

Comment: Great, thanks! That works as needed

Comment: How would I modify the code if I wanted the property to hold only for rows (or columns) instead of both? Thanks @MarcoB

Comment: @AG1123 As mentioned in the description, `Total` sums the columns of the matrix; `Map[Total]` sums the rows. So instead of `Through[{Total, Map[Total]}@mat]` you can just have one of those only: e.g. `Total @ mat` will do the check over the columns; whereas `Total /@ mat` will do it over the rows (note the difference between `@` and `/@`).

Comment: Thanks @MarcoB. However, I noticed the following strange behaviour. If I have a matrix like {{1-a,0},{0,b}} and run the row check (using  Total /@) on them I get False as a result, instead of True. If I substitute 1-a with say c, I get the expected behaviour. Any ideas why this happens? Cheers

Answer (score 4):

```
m = {{0, a, 0}, {b, 0, 0}, {0, 0, c}};
f[m_] := AllTrue[
  Count[#, 0] & /@ Join[m, Transpose[m]], # >= Length@m - 1 &]
```

> `True`

**Original**

```
f[m_] := Nor @@ (AllTrue[#, EqualTo[0]] & /@ Join[m, Transpose[m]]);
m = {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 0}};
n = {{1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}};
f[m]
f[n]
```

> `False`

> `True`

Comment: Thanks but your code does not return the correct result. Both example matrices should return False, since they both have a row or column with more than one non zero elements.

Comment: @AG1123 Thanks! I have fixed it.

Comment: Thanks! I like how concise your solution is, even though I don't really understand it.